# Can neo4j 3.* enterprise edition can control user data's access permission？

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j enterprise edition, and I found neo4j have no user data access control strategy, such as on user can grant some data's read/write permission to other user?

I found this: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4-preview/security/authentication-authorization/subgraph-access-control/

The title is "Subgraph access control" but the content is control procedure's execution permission. It look likes have no relation with subgraph's access control...

I also found some people said that writing code to implement interface SecurityRole can resolve the problem, I can't found more information about this, is this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Subgraph access control is about restricting a user's ability to access the graph so that they can only go through the procedures granted to them. The code in the procedures should encapsulate the kind of queries you want them to be able to use, so either the procedures contain the queries in full, or it allows queries but performs filtering at some level.

While this can work, it may not have the right granularity for what you're trying to do, and it is a somewhat clunky approach.

Additional work is being done to fill in those gaps.

In the upcoming Neo4j 3.4, you will have the ability to [restrict access to properties of nodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4-preview/security/authentication-authorization/property-level-security/), though this is across all nodes, not just nodes of certain labels, and it will rely on a blacklist that is defined in the neo4j.conf file, so (at this point) requiring a restart to change which roles are blacklisted from accessing certain properties (though you should be able to grant roles to users through procs as usual, no restart needed).

There's more work to be done on this of course, it's just a matter of feature prioritization, so richer options are likely to be introduced in later releases.